# need to add parameter to my ant release build.xml

Tags: java, xml, ant, build, jenkins

Currently, I am using jenkins to run my build.xml and ant release to generate .apk

I need to pass parameter to ant release (  ant release `-Dcustompackagename='com.google.android.projection.kitchensink'` ) and generate second apk .

Basically, I need to do the following :

1. run ant release to generate apk1 ( already in place )
2. run ant release `-Dcustompackagename='com.google.android.projection.kitchensink'` to generate apk2 ( not currently in place )

How do I modify my ant build.xml to achieve the second step?

Answer (score 0):

If you already have `custompackagename` property within your `build.xml` with **default value** that is used by step #1, then all you need for step #2 is:

- Add second **Invoke Ant** build step under job configuration.
- Configure *Targets* (if required).
- Click <kbd>**Advanced...**</kbd> button.
- Under *Properties*, enter:
  `-Dcustompackagename='com.google.android.projection.kitchensink'`